# 4 queries in case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have 4 queries

```
1.query = (select /*smthing*/ from my_table where /*conditions*/ and rownum = 1)
2.query = (select /*smthing*/ from my_table where /*conditions*/ and rownum = 1)
3.query = (select /*smthing*/ from my_table where /*conditions*/ and rownum = 1)
4.query = (select /*smthing*/ from my_table where /*conditions*/ and rownum = 1)
```

All the queris are working fine.

I want to use `CASE statement`:

```
 Case 
      when 1.query = NULL then 2.query
      when 2. query = NULL then 3.query
      else 4.query
 END
```

**I want to get only 1 result**. But it returns more than 1 result.

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Show your attempt code

Comment: What is your context to use `CASE`? In a `SELECT` query or in `pl/sql`? Did it run although you use `= NULL` instead of `IS NULL`? Did you try `COALESCE`? What is your RDBMS? It is stranger for oracle with that grammar `colx = ()...`

Comment: @PhamX.Bach 1.query = () - meanst that, this is the first query... just for understand the sequence...

Comment: So your `CASE` statement above is not the actual query you run. Could you post it with full context that make `it returns more than 1 result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would combine this all into one expression:

```
select s.*
from (select /*smthing*/,
             row_number() over (order by case when <conditions1> then 1
                                              when <conditions2> then 2
                                              when <conditions3> then 3
                                              when <conditions4> then 4
                                              else 5
                                         end
                               ) as seqnum
      from my_table 
     ) s
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL `=` is not used with `NULL`. Always try using `IS NULL` or `NOT NULL` etc. Try as below:

```
Case 
      when 1.query IS NULL then 2.query
      when 2. query IS NULL then 3.query
      else 4.query
 END
```

Comment: if the 1.query is not null then what will return. The above query looks like return 4.query for 1.query is not null.

Comment: Obviously he wants the same

Answer (score 0):

On Scott's schema with the following data:

```
SQL> select * from dept order by deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL> select * from emp  order by deptno;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81      10000                    10
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975                    20
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.83       1100                    20
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        920                    20
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.81       1250        500         30
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.81       1500          0         30
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300         30
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        950                    30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.81       2850                    30
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.81       1250       1400         30

14 rows selected.

SQL> select * from bonus;

ENAME      JOB              SAL       COMM
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
KING       PRESIDENT       1000        100
```

a query that utilizes UNION (which means that all queries' column list you use have to match in number and datatype) might look like this; the first column returned shows which query the resulting set belongs to.

```
SQL> with
  2    q1 as (select 'q1' what, deptno, dname, null from dept  where deptno = &par_deptno),
  3    q2 as (select 'q2' what, deptno, ename, job  from emp   where job = '&par_job'),
  4    q3 as (select 'q3' what, null  , ename, job  from bonus where ename = '&par_ename'),
  5    --
  6    qc1 as (select count(*) cnt from q1),
  7    qc2 as (select count(*) cnt from q2),
  8    qc3 as (select count(*) cnt from q3)
  9    --
 10  select q1.* from q1 join qc1 on 1 = 1 join qc2 on 1 = 1 where qc1.cnt > 0
 11  union all
 12  select q2.* from q2 join qc2 on 1 = 1 join qc1 on 1 = 1 where qc2.cnt > 0 and qc1.cnt = 0
 13  union all
 14  select q3.* from q3 join qc3 on 1 = 1 join qc1 on 1 = 1 join qc2 on 1 = 1
 15      where qc3.cnt > 0 and qc1.cnt = 0 and qc2.cnt = 0;
Enter value for par_deptno: 10
Enter value for par_job: CLERK
Enter value for par_ename: WHO

WH     DEPTNO DNAME                NULL
-- ---------- -------------------- ---------
q1         10 ACCOUNTING

SQL> /
Enter value for par_deptno: 15
Enter value for par_job: CLERK
Enter value for par_ename: WHO

WH     DEPTNO DNAME                NULL
-- ---------- -------------------- ---------
q2         20 SMITH                CLERK
q2         20 ADAMS                CLERK
q2         30 JAMES                CLERK
q2         10 MILLER               CLERK

SQL> /
Enter value for par_deptno: 15
Enter value for par_job: NONE
Enter value for par_ename: KING

WH     DEPTNO DNAME                NULL
-- ---------- -------------------- ---------
q3            KING                 PRESIDENT

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in some different ways, one of the simple way is this:

```
  select * from(
    (query1)
    UNION
    (query2)
     UNION
    (query3)
     UNION
    (query4)   ) where rownum = 1
```

it means :

```
  select * from(
    (select /*smthing*/ from my_table where /*conditions*/ and rownum = 1)
    UNION
    (select /*smthing*/ from my_table where /*conditions*/ and rownum = 1)
     UNION
    (select /*smthing*/ from my_table where /*conditions*/ and rownum = 1)
     UNION
    (select /*smthing*/ from my_table where /*conditions*/ and rownum = 1)
  ) where rownum = 1
```

order of queries is important.